# Dynamic template Angular based on database configuration

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular application and in some interfaces I need to show/hide some divs based on user configuration that is retrieved from my database.

I was thinking about using *ngIf and doing something like this:

```
<div *ngIf=“hasConfig(‘blue’)>
      Blue div
</div>

<div *ngIf=“hasConfig(‘yellow’)>
      Yellow div
</div>

<div *ngIf=“hasConfig(‘red’)>
      Red div
</div>
```

But I’m afraid that it will harm my app performance and get a little bit messy, because the same situation happens in several parts of my app.
And these divs have fields, each with a ngModel that can be sent to the server, it’s like all of them togheter constitute one single form.

The same applies to the main menu, I need to show menus based on permissions that the users are given by an admin. Today I’m doing this with *ngIf, but I’m not sure if that’s the best approach.

Are there any good practices or solutions that won’t slow down my app in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

ngIf is indeed the best way to show/hide sections of your UI based on user permissions.

You can also protect routes with Router Guards (e.g. CanActivate).

If you fetch the user's permissions in each Component, you may indeed slow your application down somewhat, so I would suggest fetching them once at login - the most performant way would be to return the permissions upon a successful login request.

You'll want to do this with a Service that is shared among all of your components and which caches the result.

If instead, you send a separate request for permissions after login, that will slow things down a bit. Whether the delay is noticeable will depend on how long that second request takes to complete.

Comment: Interesting. I’m already fetching the permissions with a shared service. And Elen it comes to a specific component that needs to fetch custom configuration I’m doing that inside onInit. But in terms of rendering performance *ngIf would be my best option so?